# Physically migrate MySQL without a dump

Tags: mysql, migration

A client ask me to migrate his MySQL DB:
The server doesn't have free space and it also has a very big table that is broken, so I can't dump it.

I can't REPAIR it because of lacking of free space.

Question : Is there a way to physically move MySQL DB data files to another server and use them for the "new" MySQL ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

- Old DB Server : 10.1.2.30
- New DB Server : 10.1.2.40

STEP 01) On the Old Server, `service mysql stop`

STEP 02) On the Old Server, `rsync -av --progress /var/lib/mysql root@10.1.2.40:/var/lib/mysql`

STEP 03) On the New Server, `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

STEP 04) On the New Server, `service mysql start`

Make sure `/var/lib/mysql` on the New Server is on a much bigger disk mount

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, I was already donwloading those files from `/var/lib/mysql` so when its finished I just have to upload that to New DB Server. Thanks.

Comment: Above rsync command created a mysql folder in `/var/lib/mysql`. And I know that mysql already has a mysql in it. So I had both `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` and `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/mysql`

Comment: is it possible to do this without stopping the old server first (service mysql stop)

Answer (score 5):

You can also migrate it on-the-fly to another server, sending data through pipes and SSH. It's useful if the target host have a different MySQL version, for example.

I just wrote a blog post explaining how I did it:

http://techutils.bcmedeiros.dev/2016/02/on-fly-database-migration-between-two.html

There is an explanation there, but if you don't care, just run something like below.

Target host:

```
nc -l 3456 | \
  gunzip | \
  pv | \
  mysql -u tdb_user -ptdb_pass targetdatabase
```

Source host:

```
mysqldump -u sdb_user -psdb_pass sourcedatabase | \
  pv | \
  gzip | \
  ssh sshuser@targethost nc 127.0.0.1 3456
```

Comment: I like your way of thinking