# MySQL server migration to new hardware

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, migration

I have to migrate working DB from old server (~50 Gb, mysql-5.5.43, openvz, all data in InnoDB) to a new hardware and new mysql version (mysql-5.6.28, debian). DB is "alone" - no replica servers. Dumps regulary made by mysqldump. Also software on PHP is running on server

Simple move using mysqldump isn't ok, 'cause restoring base is longs about 8 hours. I have no window of time for this...

So, there's a thought: make new server as a slave to existing server, wait till mysql replication sync is done,  turn off old server, make slave become master and continue working. Is this possible? Will be there any software-kind problems?

Or, this thought is wrong. If so, how, then, I have to migrate my DB to new hardware and software with minimal downtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you're managing your own database instead of AWS managed database.

1. Make sure you did backup the database, just in case accidental disaster. By default, your database located at `/var/lib/mysql`. Copy that to a safe place.
2. [Upgrade your old database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963923/how-do-i-update-mysql-5-7-to-the-new-mysql-8-0)
3. [Migrate using rsync](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36345/physically-migrate-mysql-without-a-dump)

Answer (score 0):

In your case restoring database is taking more time, so I suggest to use **AWS database migration service**.

It's very simple,less human work and fastest method. And also your real time data will sync.
Instead of replication use this.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution isn't for this task. We don't use any Amazon or other web-services for storing DB. All infrastructure is closed and not for web-access